# data.frame tags usage failed

Tags: r

I've created 3 vectors:

> v1 = c(1,2,3)
>   v2 = c(11,22,33)
>   v3 = c(111,222,333)

Then I've made a frame from them:

```
> df = data.frame(vec1 = v1, vec2 = v2, vec3 = v3)                                                                                                                                
> df
  vec1 vec2 vec3
1    1   11  111
2    2   22  222
3    3   33  333
```

It seems like column names is not automatic now, but `vec1, vec2, vec3`.

After this I want to get a frame row where `vec2` is equal to 11:

```
> df[vec2 == 11,]
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, vec2 == 11, ) : object 'vec2' not found
```

But the following code works:

```
> df[v2 == 11,]
  vec1 vec2 vec3
1    1   11  111
```

I think this is wrong. I don't understand why `R` uses old vector names, instead of tags `vec1, vec2, vec3`.

Is it a bug of my version of `R`?

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0/x86_64 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use:

```
df[df$vec2 == 11, ]
```

or

```
df[with(df, vec2 == 11), ]
```

The second one worked because `v2 == 11` evaluates to `TRUE, FALSE, FALSE` and so, the first row was being printed. However, `vec2` is not a variable that is set. It is a column of a `data.frame`. So, you'll have to identify it as such with `df$vec2` (or use `with`)

Answer (score 2):

When you use the following syntax :

```
df[vec2 == 11,]
```

R is trying to select rows of `df` based on the values of the `vec2` vector. But there is no such vector : there is only a column of your data frame with this name. So the syntax you are looking for is :

```
df[df$vec2 == 11,]
```

The following works because the vector has been defined previously in your R session :

```
df[v2 == 11,]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug but rather a misinterpretation - delete `v2` using `rm(v2)` and `df[v2 == 11,]` would fail. One can use `subset()` to subset a data frame using column names:

```
> subset(df, vec2 == 11)
  vec1 vec2 vec3
1    1   11  111
```

`subset` also supports extraction of specific columns, e.g.

```
> subset(df, vec2 == 11, select = vec1:vec2)
  vec1 vec2
1    1   11
```

Comment: That's why it is always a good idea to further read into the documentation of everything, suggested on the Internet :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the said syntax if you [attach](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#attach_0028_0029-and-detach_0028_0029) `df` first:

```R
df = data.frame(vec1 = v1, vec2 = v2, vec3 = v3)
attach(df)
df[vec2 == 11,]
```

will output:

```R
   vec1 vec2 vec3
1    1   11  111
```

While this can be helpful while working on the console in terms of sheer typing it avoids, it should be generally avoided during scripting as per [the Google R style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html#attach).